# How to call a matlab class method out of a matlab function without instantiating

Tags: matlab, function, class, oop, simulink

I've created a matlab class and would like to call every simulation cycle a public method out of a matlab function in Simulink.

**matlab class:**

```
...
function fcn(inst)
...
```

**matlab function:**

```
...
i = classInst;
fcn(i);
...
```

It seems every simulation cycle the class will be instantiated and for this reason, the method doesn't work.

**How can I call the class method of one instance several times out of a m-file?**

Thank you

Comment: It's slightly unclear what the structure of your code is, and what your desired structure is, but it sounds like you want "static" methods...

Comment: create a static method in the class. Look at this:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/static-methods.html

Answer (score 0):

Use persistent keyword combined with isempty check to create and store the instance. Use the following pattern in your code.

```
function y = fcn(u)

persistent obj
if isempty(obj)
  obj = MyObj;
end

y = method(MyObj, u);
```

For this code, your class will be instantiated only once. It can have properties that will hold values between each call.

Comment: Thank you Navan, your answer was exactly I was looking for. It works fine.

Comment: How is `MyObj` initialized? Are `obj` and `MyObj` swapped on some lines?

Comment: MyObj is class. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/create-a-simple-class.html for defining classes in MATLAB.